# display hadoop content c#

Tags: c#, hadoop

i would like to get list of files available in my hdfs cluster using .net.
the problem is when i run the code in the main method in Program.cs it worked .and when i try to use the code in a button, the application hungs, it blocks.
Here is the code

```
using Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce; 
try {
    IHadoop mycluster = Hadoop.Connect();
    string[] content = mycluster.StorageSystem.LsFiles("/");
    foreach (string s in content) {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
} catch (Exception exException) {
    MessageBox.Show (exException.Message);
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: How about adding a bit more info? Just saying the code hangs, is not really something we can do anything about it. Except for thinking it might be a threading issue, but that would be just guessing. Can you show the working console code, how do you call the function...

Comment: Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new Form1());
           
          try{
              
                IHadoop mycluster = Hadoop.Connect();
                string[] content = mycluster.StorageSystem.LsFiles("/");
                foreach (string s in content)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (exException.Message);
            }

Comment: the code i gave i put in the Program.cs , i do the same the same code , but taking of the comment of /Application.Run(new Form1()) , i put the same code on a button and launch forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute code synchrounously in a WinForms event handler, no UI operations will be performed in that time, because you block the UI thread that handles the Windows message pump. So whenever you have lengthy operations and you want your UI to be reactive, you *have* to run them in a separate task/thread.

Running operations in a separate task comes with the additional challenge that you have to marshal all UI operations back into the UI thread, because you'll run into an error if you run them in a thread other than the UI thread.

I assume you have a regular `Click` handler both parameters `sender`and `e` (and you are in .NET 4.5 - otherwise you have to use `Task.Factory` to run the task):

```
Task.Run(() => {
    try {
        IHadoop mycluster = Hadoop.Connect();
        string[] content = mycluster.StorageSystem.LsFiles("/");
        foreach (string s in content) {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    } catch (Exception exException) {
        MethodInvoker invoker = delegate() { MessageBox.Show (exException.Message); };
        ((Control)sender).Invoke(invoker);
    }
});
```

Comment: when i put a comment on   ((Control)sender).Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show (exException.Message)); it works fine and i get result , but when keep it i got this error Cannot convert lambda operations to type system.delegate because it is not a delegate type .Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks my friend very much you saved me .but please can you explain me what you putted in the catch because i couldn't understand what it actually does thanks again

Comment: That is the marshal into the UI thread. Showing a message box is a UI operation and as such has to be executed in the UI thread. [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) takes care of that.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help .